# Grails: Conditionally Load Spring Security LDAP Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have an app that runs in multiple production environments.  In one environment we want to authenticate with LDAP, in the other we do not.  If the Spring Security LDAP plugin is included in BuildConfig.groovy, the non-LDAP environment fails to authenticate because LDAP is not configured.

I tried

```
environments {
    devldap {
        plugins {
            compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2"
        }
    }
}
```

but the LDAP plugin still builds with the non-LDAP environment and causes the non-LDAP environment (in this case `development`) to fail to authenticate if I don't include the LDAP configuration because it can't connect to LDAP.

I've tried

```
grails clean
grails refresh-dependencies
```

but the LDAP plugin only uninstalls if I completely comment it out.

How can I conditionally include/exclude a plugin in my build?

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is a bit old now, however I do a similar thing with the Melody plugin. There is no value in this being installed during TEST - and can get in the way - so I do the following:

```
plugins {
    // other plugins ...

    if( Environment.current != Environment.TEST )
        compile ":grails-melody:1.56.0"

    // other plugins ...
}
```

So when I run 'test-app' I see the plugin 'uninstalled' and then when I do 'run-app' I see it installed and it's available.

*NOTE:* I recently got caught out by forgetting to also do an `import grails.util.Environment`. If you do that, you'll find that `Environment.current == [:]` as does `Environment.TEST` etc. I believe this is due to the builder behind the config file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out when I get a chance. As it turns out, I ended up removing ldap from that project altogether later on for other reasons, but it's good to know that this is possible. Thanks again.